# WinAPI to configure control buttons on title (caption) bar

Tags: windows, winapi, user-interface

Help me to find out an WinAPI functionality to configure control buttons on window title (minimize, maximize, close).

I search functionality for show and hide of buttons, like shown on example:

http://screencloud.net/v/3yeP

As actual result I'm try to create window without any control buttons and then by need show buttons.

Platforms:

- Windows 7 (Desktop);
- Windows 8 (Desktop);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WinAPI these are Windows style bits, changed using `SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWL_STYLE, ...)` ([doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644898%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). The style bits are documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632600%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), you are probably interested in `WS_MINIMIZEBOX`, `WS_MAXIMIZEBOX` and `WS_SYSMENU`. There are no `WS_CLOSE` style, as long as there is anything at all there will be a "Close" button.

You may need to call `SetWindowPos(hWnd, ..., SWP_FRAMECHANGED)` ([doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) after that to make the style change effective.